# Bi-directional database synchronization

Tags: database, synchronization

Anyone can give some advice on C# frameworks/opensource projects for bi-drectional database synchronisation?

I have an application that will be used by multiple users. Normally, the user will interact with the application's local database (MS ACCESS) as we assume the network is not available on-site most of the time.  When the user has network connectivity, the local database is to be synchronised with the centralised remote database (MS SQL). In the end, all users are able to read/write/commit each others' data. It very much like a SVN repository, i think.

Has anyone tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629326.aspx? how does it fare? I have not really look into it, i am trying to look for more options first before evaluating each.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753)?

It was designed with scenarios like yours in mind.

- [Introduction to Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992)
- [Sync Framework Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902852.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Sync service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg298975%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Sync Service in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg299072%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Definitely worth reading! ... now just seeing if there are other options.